# Backup and Restore Single App After Upgrade

Tags: ios, software-update, restore

When I update iOS over the air, the process seems to include all apps being automatically updated.

However, I have one single app from the App Store (Overdrive) that I would like to keep stable and not updated.

After the update, I would like to still have the *same* version of this app, with the *same* data, as before the update.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What steps do you take to "update the iOS"? Over the Air updates are handled differently than iTunes updates. What sort of App is in question? There are apps bundled with the OS, there are apps that come from MDM, apps that come signed by developers and enterprise accounts. Apple has B2B custom stores, the iOS app store at large, etc... We could say "yes - you can sometimes do what you ask" but that's a lot of work to push off on the answerer to cover all the possible bases if you have a more specific question you want solved.

Comment: @bmike Good points; sorry I wasn't more specific. In the past I have updated over the air. And the app in question is not built in. Overdrive is library reading software downloadable through Apple's store.

Comment: Al - much better ask now. +1 from me. I edited the post so that when the comments get cleared out (as they often do), the meat of the issue is explained in the post itself. Cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a built-in Apple app, then no.
Otherwise, just don't update that app when asked.
Eventually, though, you will get to a point where the old version may no longer work on the new OS.

Check that you don't have automatic downloads set in Settings > iTunes & App Store, then non-Apple apps will not update until you tell them to, from App Store app itself.

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks for your response ... When I checked at the Apple store, the Apple "expert" told me I could not update the OS without simultaneously updating the apps. Is that incorrect?

Comment: 3rd party apps will update on their own schedule. If you don't have then set up update automatically, they won't until you tell them to. I've added a bit to the answer...

Comment: It's funny, when I updated the OS before, no apps were automatically updating themselves. It was only during the OTA update this was happening. It's as if the OS updated, the new version of iOS was set to automatically update all apps, and apps started updating before I knew what was happening! ... I'll be more vigilant next time.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... not sure what you need, but be aware that eventually your old app may quit working with the next version or even the next 8.? update.

But, to answer your question, connect your iDevice to iTunes (preferably on a Mac, but a Windows PC should work as well). Hopefully, you downloaded this app to disk already. If not, you will need to find it from an archive and download it. Some older versions of signed apps may still be available by the developer, though this is getting harder to find. If nothing else, grab an iOS 4.2 or 5 device and access the App Store with it. In some generous cases, you will be prompted to downgrade app versions and get to keep the old app. Once you do, you can backup, and thereby copy that app to your Mac (or PC). In iTunes preferences, turn automatic updates and downloads OFF. This will preserve your old versions -- but beware that you will have to stay up to date on your stuff yourself.

So, back to the original suggestion. Connect your iDevice to iTunes. Back it up completely, then do a total restore, if you haven't done this already. Find the app that you want to restore. If there are two versions, Get Info on both to find the legacy version. Delete the new app from iOS, then drag and drop the old one. Click Sync and wait. Click the eject button when done, and disconnect your device. You're done.

Good luck.